# Backend massaction(grid) selectAll in not working

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, massaction

In Magento admin grid, select all alone is not selecting all the checkboxes, whereas select visible, unselect visible and unselect all is working fine. What might be the issue? help me to resolve this issue!

[image]

```
     <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="dckap_samplerequests_orders.grid"
         as="grid">
         <arguments>
             <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">requestsGrid</argument>
             <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Orders\Collection</argument>
             <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
             <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
             <argument name="use_ajax" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
             <argument name="grid_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/grid">
                 <param name="_current">1</param>
             </argument>
         </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction" 
                name="vendor_module_orders.grid.massaction" as="grid.massaction">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="massaction_id_field" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                    <argument name="form_field_name" xsi:type="string">orders</argument>
                    <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="status1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Status to Processing</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massStatus/status/2</item>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure want to update Status?</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="status2" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Status to Completed</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massStatus/status/3</item>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure want to update Status?</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="status3" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Status to Rejected</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massStatus/status/4</item>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure want to update Status?</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="delete" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massDelete</item>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure want to delete?</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" 
                name="vendor_module_orders.grid.columnSet" as="grid.columnSet">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="path" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                        <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="id">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                            ID
                        </argument>
                        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">request_id</argument>
                        <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Increment</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>


            </block>
     </block>
  </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: show us the xml code for the column

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue. 
Problem: Invalid id given for massaction_id_field in XML. After updating it ( to Schema's primary column name, it works like a charm!